# Html form with automatic submit

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I have a problem with html forms, I searched for a solutions on google but I didn't find any help. I want to do a html form without submit button, like [here](http://handsonaswegrow.com/) (search for activities:) , when I select option it redirect me to the value of option selected

Comment: You can do it by jQuery.

Comment: @user3659034, yeah I'm thinking some sort of select on change.

Comment: http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/forms/navmenu.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bind a change event handler to your select element and call the `submit()` method of the form when it is triggered.

Then have your server side form handler redirect to the page you want.

```
<form action="redirector">
    <select name="destination">
        <option value="1">Some page</option>
        <option value="2">Some other page</option>
    </select>
    <!-- Normal submit button for when the JS fails -->
    <input type="submit" value="Go">
</form>
<script>
document.querySelector('select').addEventListener('change', submitForm);
function submitForm(event) {
    event.target.form.submit();
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a javascript question.  Using jQuery, you would do it something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function($){
    $("select").on("change",function(){
        window.location.href = "http://example.com/"+$(this).val();
    });
});
```